# pasting two dataframes of different sizes

Tags: r, match, extract, subset, paste

I would like to paste strings from 2 dfs `n` and `p` - `dput` at the end.
They have different sizes`nrow(n) = 25` and `nrow(p) = 20` 
with two factors  : `factor1` (binary) and `factor2`(integers)

---

```
head(n,3)                       head(p,3)
string   factor1  factor2        string    factor1  factor2
--       --       --             --        --       --
h        f1       5              i         f1       1
h        f1       6              c         f1       2
h        f1       7              c         f1       3
```

---

```
tail(n,3)                       tail(p,3)
string   factor1  factor2        string    factor1  factor2
--       --       --             --        --       --
a        f2       27             h         f2       18
g        f2       28             i         f2       19
b        f2       29             i         f2       20
```

Here, I would like to create a dataframe

1. which does not omit any factors
2. pastes the strings of n and p when set of factors are the same
3. if only one unique set of factors is available, paste one value

---

```
output <- paste (p - n) # error n an p different length
output <- merge (p,n, all=T) # merge into one df
output <- tapply(output, 1, paste) # same error
output <- tapply(output[which((output$factor == output$factor & output$factor2 == output$factor2 ))], 1, paste) # nonsensical
```

---

Apologies for the lack of "minimal code"...

### ----

Intended output:

```
head(output)                   tail(output)
string   factor   factor2        string    factor   factor2
--       --       --             --        --       --
i        f1       1              g         f2       24
c        f1       2              e         f1       25
c        f1       3              j         f1       26
g        f1       4              a         f2       27
fh       f1       5              g         f2       28  
ih       f1       6              b         f2       29
```

### -----

```
> dput(n)
    structure(list(string = structure(c(7L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 
6L, 2L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "g", "h", "j"), class = "factor"), 
    factor = c("f1", "f1", "f1", "f1", "f1", "f1", "f1", "f1", 
    "f1", "f1", "f2", "f2", "f2", "f2", "f2", "f2", "f2", "f2", 
    "f2", "f2", "f1", "f1", "f2", "f2", "f2"), factor2 = 5:29), .Names = c("string", 
"factor", "factor2"), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = "data.frame")

> dput(p)
     structure(list(string = structure(c(5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("c", 
"f", "g", "h", "i", "j"), class = "factor"), factor = c("f1", 
"f1", "f1", "f1", "f1", "f1", "f1", "f1", "f1", "f1", "f2", "f2", 
"f2", "f2", "f2", "f2", "f2", "f2", "f2", "f2"), factor2 = 1:20), .Names = c("string", 
"factor", "factor2"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `purrr` we can first do `full_join`, then `paste` a vector of the two strings from which we omit the NAs:

```
library(tidyverse)
full_join(n, p, by = c('factor', 'factor2')) %>% 
  mutate(string = map2(as.character(string.x), as.character(string.y), 
                       ~paste0(na.omit(c(.y, .x)), collapse = ''))) %>% 
  select(-string.x, -string.y)
```

> ```
>    factor factor2 string
> 1      f1       5     fh
> 2      f1       6     ih
> 3      f1       7     ih
> 4      f1       8     jd
> 5      f1       9     he
> 6      f1      10     jb
> 7      f1      11      b
> 8      f1      12      a
> 9      f1      13      d
> 10     f1      14      a
> 11     f2      15     ja
> 12     f2      16     jb
> 13     f2      17     jc
> 14     f2      18     ha
> 15     f2      19     id
> 16     f2      20     ia
> 17     f2      21      j
> 18     f2      22      j
> 19     f2      23      b
> 20     f2      24      g
> 21     f1      25      e
> 22     f1      26      j
> 23     f2      27      a
> 24     f2      28      g
> 25     f2      29      b
> 26     f1       1      i
> 27     f1       2      c
> 28     f1       3      c
> 29     f1       4      g
> 30     f2      11      j
> 31     f2      12      i
> 32     f2      13      h
> 33     f2      14      j
> ```

In base R:

```
np <- merge(n, p, c('factor', 'factor2'), all = TRUE)
np$string <- mapply(function(x, y) paste0(na.omit(c(x, y)), collapse = ''), 
                    as.character(np$string.y), as.character(np$string.x))
np[, -c(3:4)]
```

Comment: hello @Axeman, thanks for the answer - will run the code. looking at your output, the string variable should be a paste of n[string] and p[string]. in your output it should be output[1,string]=fh  output[2,string]=ih

Comment: Sorry forgot an `as.character`.

Comment: thanks @Axeman, this answer my question. in my real life problem i have N  number of columns `strings` in `np` 
using  `np[,2:5]` for `np$string.y` and `np[,6:9]` for `np$string.x` seems impossible - would you have a suggestion? cheers